# Syntax highlight embedded script

Tags: syntax-highlighting, multiple-modes

I have a bash shell script that has a fairly sizable amount of perl code in it. Is there a why to get perl syntax highlighting instead of the normal here doc coloring? Thank you for any help, I'm new to emacs and still getting the hang of elisp and the terminology

Comment: Try the solutions for [multiple modes](https://emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes).

Comment: thanks, mmm-mode seems to work well. I'm having a hard time getting to automatically recognize the perl code. As i said i have perl script in a bash here doc. parse region seems to get it when i do it manually

Answer (score -2):

You can just M-x `perl-mode` to activate perl mode.

Or, set a easy key to perl-mode. For example,

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f8>") 'perl-mode)
```

Or, you can put add this comment to the first line in the bash file

```
# -*- mode: perl -*-
```

then, it'll open with perl mode.

Or, you can put the following at the bottom

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (perl-mode 1)
# End:
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I wanted this in shell highlight  
  
  #!/usr/bin/env bash  
  for file in $(find $HOME -depth 1 -name ".*"); do  
      echo $file  
  done  
  
  sudo perl <<-'PERL' #&> /dev/null  
  # this in perl highlighting  
  #!/usr/bin/env perl  
  #****************************************************************************************  
  # libraries used  
  #****************************************************************************************  
  use strict;  
  use warnings;

Comment: @GaryAsh See https://emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes but i don't think they'll be smooth, as emacs is designed for just 1 major mode per buffer.